# Android - Get resource id from another resource

Tags: android, resources, drawable

Let's say that I have a drawable :

```
foo.png
```

At certain point in my program, it receives one of two possible string keys: "img_foo1" or "img_foo2", which I want to use to retrieve the same "foo" drawable.

So I tried accessing the drawable from other two resources in the way of:

```
<drawable name="img_foo1">@drawable/foo</drawable>
<drawable name="img_foo2">@drawable/foo</drawable>
```

Then I thought that I could use getResources().getIdentifier() with those key names, however that gives me the ID of img_foo1, and img_foo2, but not the ID of drawable foo.

Is there any way I could get the resource ID to which these resources are referencing?

**edit:**

The reason I do this, is because I receive these keys from an external source from which I have no control. The only thing that I can do, is somehow map the known keys to the corresponding drawables to draw the correct image (because the same image may be used by different keys).

I could achieve this with an static collection which I can initialize with the app, however I'm trying to help me with the resources instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`getValue()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getValue%28int,%20android.util.TypedValue,%20boolean%29), passing `false` for the last parameter. I guess you'll now get the reference to `@drawable/foo` in the `TypedValue` whose id you can now retrieve. I haven't tried it; let me know if you give it a shot.

Comment: good, worked very well. the name must be `(getPackage() + ":drawable" + key)`, and the value is inside `typedValue.data`, if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain a little bit more about why you are trying to do things this way? You normally would not use a string at all. Additionally, I am unfamiliar with using drawables like that.

As far as I know, you want to simply have one drawable that is foo.png.  If you want to use that in various layouts, that's fine - just use image views.  For all resources, you will want to keep track of the integer values in the program (R.drawable.foo, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Well , not fully clean but I on the meantime I managed to get the drawable Id with this:

```
int keyId = getResources().getIdentifier(key, "drawable", getPackageName());

int drawableId = getResources().getIdentifier(getString(keyId).replace("res/","").replace(".png",""),null,getPackageName());
```